# Curve arc between two sections

Tags: css, svg, css-shapes

How can i can make a curvy arc between two sections using CSS or SVG like this one :
(the orange arc between the grey section and the blue footer)
[image]

Comment: You can do it in multiple ways. How are you approaching this? Can you include some code? I would have used an extra div element with position absolute and pseudo elements but that's just me.

Comment: @DebsmitaPaul thank you, i tried that but i couldn't do it exactly as the example

Answer (score 1):

multiple background and clip-path

```css
.box {
  height:300px;
  background:
    radial-gradient(75%  95% at 56% 100%,blue 99%,transparent)
    orange;
  clip-path:ellipse(80% 100% at 50% 100%)
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```